# Split 2d numpy array on specific Y coordinate

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a screenshot with RGB values for each pixel saved as numpy array, and i want to split it where Y == n

(Y is the main array and the x arrays are inside of each Y.)

Comment: Just use Python indexing notation? `array1 = array[:n]; array2 = array[n:]`

Comment: @jsbueno Yes that's what i needed , thanks.